# Text selection (the blue background) fills only padding at top in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, selection, padding, textselection

I have a inline element with padding at the top and bottom. If I select the text, in Chrome the selection fills (vertically) the top padding, but not the bottom padding:

```html
<span style="background-color:grey; padding: 10px 0;">selected this text</span>
```

Run that code and select the text. In my Chrome (Version 60 on a Mac) it looks like this (the blue is the selection):

[image: Selected text]

Why is the selection only stretched to the top and not to the bottom? Either I want it stretched in both directions or at least none. How can I achive that? Hopfully without additional tags.

By the way: In Firefox it streches in no direction, in Safari just to the bottom?!

Comment: Changing the display type to `inline-block` does not stretch the selection, in Chrome anyway

Answer (score 0):

Well do not know the exact reason of why this is happening but changing it `display: inline-block` fixes it for now

Comment: the intention is to make it stretch in both directions, now it doesn't

Comment: @rebecca Yes, better would be in both directions. However, as I said above, no streching at all is also a step forward.

Comment: my bad, sorry about that!